# Correct way to initialize std::vector data member

Tags: c++, class, stdvector

```cpp
// Method One
class ClassName
{
public:
    ClassName() : m_vecInts() {}
    
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vecInts;
};
```

```cpp
// Method Two
class ClassName
{
public:
    ClassName() {} // do nothing
    
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vecInts;
};
```

What is the correct way to initialize the `std::vector` data member of the class?
Do we have to initialize it at all?

Comment: No, not unless you want to specify an initial capacity (or initialize it's content which you can do with initializer lists in C++11 or boost's `list_of` I _think_).

Comment: Both way's vector gets constructed using default constructor , but 1st is preferred

Comment: If you don't mention it at all in your initializer list, the default constructor will be called. Otherwise, call whichever constructor is appropriate (e.g. maybe you want it to have 100 default constructed elements).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization

> Default initialization is performed in three situations:
>
> 1. when a variable with automatic storage duration is declared with no initializer
> 2. when an object with dynamic storage duration is created by a new-expression without an initializer
> 3. when a base class or a **non-static data member is not mentioned in a constructor initializer list and that constructor is called**.
>
> The effects of default initialization are:
>
> - If T is a **class type, the default constructor is called to provide the initial value for the new object**.
> - If T is an array type, every element of the array is default-initialized.
> - Otherwise, nothing is done.

Since `std::vector` is a class type its default constructor is called. So the manual initialization isn't needed.

Comment: surprise to me that `class T2 { 
    int mem;
 public:
    T2() {} // "mem" not in initializer list
};` `const T2 t2; // ok, calls the user-provided default ctor 
                 // t2.mem is default-initialized`

Comment: I just tested the above code in VS2010 and it is WRONG. the t2.mem is NOT default-initialized!

Comment: @q0987: `mem` is an `int`, it's neither a class, nor an array type, so it won't get default initialized. The code provided on cppreference is almost always verified under the C++11 standard, but I don't know whether this changes anything for the given case (given the `const` qualifier). However, even if the example is   inconsistent and maybe even wrong, the explanation and standard itself aren't.

Answer (score 32):

It depends. If you want a size 0 vector, then you don't have to do anything. If you wanted, say, a size N vector fill of 42s then use the constructor initializer lists:

```
ClassName() : m_vecInts(N, 42) {}
```

Answer (score 11):

Since C++11, you can also use [list-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) of a non-static member directly inside the class declaration:

```cpp
class ClassName
{
public:
    ClassName() {}

private:
    std::vector<int> m_vecInts {1, 2, 3}; // or = {1, 2, 3}
}
```

Comment: Is there an alternative syntax that can help when the size of the vector is very large, say when I want a vector of 40 elements, all initialized to 100?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio `std::vector<int> m_vecInts = std::vector<int>(40, 100);` will work.

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to initialise it explcitly, it will be created when you create an instance of your class.